# How can Subtype be referenced by Supertype in Go

Tags: go

Go doesn't support Polymorphism.If specific types were to be passed under the umbrella of Generic types it fails to work in Go. Following piece of code throws error . What is the best way to achieve the same functionality in Go?

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

type parent struct {
    parentID string
}

type child1 struct {
    parent
    child1ID string
}

type child2 struct {
    parent
    child2ID string
}

type childCollection struct {
    collection []parent
}

func (c *childCollection) appendChild(p parent) {
    c.collection = append(c.collection, p)
}

func main() {

    c1 := new(child1)
    c2 := new(child2)

    c := new(childCollection)
    c.appendChild(c1)
    c.appendChild(c2)

}
```

[Go Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/PaVYBJd1LrC)

Comment: "Following piece of code throws error" - what error? "What is the best way to achieve the same functionality" - what functionality? What exactly are you trying to do and what problem are you having?

Comment: @Adrian Functionality is that a subtype can be referenced by supertype. How can that be achieved here?

Comment: @guly: there are no subtypes and supertypes in go. Don't try to think of composition as inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the type Child is composed of something Parent in this case. does not mean that it is that something. These are two different types so cannot be interchangeable in this way.

Now if you had an interface Parent and your child objects meet that interface then we are talking a different thing altogether.

**Edit 1**

Example

https://play.golang.org/p/i6fQBoL2Uk7

**Edit 2**

```
package main

import "fmt"


type parent interface {
    getParentId() (string)
}

type child1 struct {
    child1ID string
}

func (c child1) getParentId() (string) {
    return c.child1ID
}

type child2 struct {
    child2ID string
}

func (c child2) getParentId() (string) {
    return c.child2ID
}

type childCollection struct {
    collection []parent
}

func (c *childCollection) appendChild(p parent) {
    c.collection = append(c.collection, p)
}

func main() {

    c1 := child1{"1"}
    c2 := child2{"2"}

    c := new(childCollection)
    c.appendChild(c1)
    c.appendChild(c2)

    fmt.Println(c)

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Quick question : Is the child 'state' available within the collection now?

Comment: Yes it would be, because they all meet the interface all you would have to do is loop them and call the method to get the individual states if that is how you set out the interface to behave.